# Are there any good books on Xen and Virtualization?

Tags: cloud, virtualization, vmware, xen

Please recommend some good books on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more detailed and theoretical
"The Definitive Guide to the Xen Hypervisor, David Chisnall".
This one has more practical approach "The Book of Xen: A Practical Guide for the System Administrator, Takemura ,Crawford"